# Docker compose mysql container runs after application that depends on it

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple java application that depends on MySQL.

This is how my `docker-compose.yaml` looks like:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  my-app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And this is my `Dockerfile` to create a containerized app, i.e. `my-app`:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/Service1-0.0.1.jar Service1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Service1.jar"]
```

When I try `docker-compose up`, the application launches Tomcat successfully, but can't connect to MySQL container, since it launches after the app:

[image]
<sup>Docker Compose Log</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, it's suppose to come up after the db container. What is the result of `docker logs docker-mysql_1 --tail 25 -f` Paste that as well.

Also, try to add a volumes section for your db container like so

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
volumes:
  - /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `volumes`, See the updated question.

Comment: Everything works just fine with the same configuration on my machine
`devert@maviance:~/Projects/smobilpay-uats$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "smobilpay-uats_default" with the default driver
Creating smobilpay-uats_docker-mysql_1 ... done
Creating smobilpay-uats_my-app_1       ... done
`
Don't know what you are doing wrong

Comment: I just say `docker-compose up` without it's rest `... -d Creating network ...`

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean. But `docker-compose up -d` is to bring up the containers from the images. the `d` flag is to start them in detached mode. Meaning you can close the terminal and containers won't shut down.

Answer (score 0):

it says this very clearly in the doc https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/
`depends_on` will only start the docker build in that order, it will not wait for the build to complete. You need to give your own `command` which will ensure that required services is started before you proceed with the next build. Or you can skip docker compose and simply use a bash script that executes `docker run` in the order you want it.